# Show list item values from different site collections

Tags: content-query-web-part

We have a site template that contains a list with columns such as title, status, manager. We use this template to create site collections. I would like to query this list item values and show them all together on a single page somewhere. As the lists span different site collections I'm guessing a content query web part is out? Any ideas how I can do this? All the site collections use a specific managed path of that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You shall prefer content search web part over content query that will work better.

Comment: I would have to name the site collections in the web part query wouldn't I? I'd rather loop through them based on the URL pattern

Answer (score 0):

I use custom webservice at the every site collection to get query results and webpart with datagrid to show it together

Comment: Problem with that is having to apply the web service to each new site collection. I'd rather it were dynamic eg foreach site that starts with server\project get the value of columns X, y and z